# Let $n \in \omega$. Suppose $f:n \to A$ is onto $A$. Prove that $A$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Let $n \in \omega$.  Suppose $f:n \to A$ is onto $A$.  Prove that $A$ is finite.

I have: Let $I_a = \{i \in n:f(i)=a\}$ for $a \in A$.  Since $f$ is onto $A$, $I_a$ is nonempty, and by the well-ordering principle, it has a least element $l$.  I know I'm to prove by induction, by I'm a bit stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What definition of infinite (or finite) are you using?

Comment: A set $X$ is finite iff there is a one-to-one function $f:X\to n$ for some natural number $n$.

Comment: Let $N$ be the smallest natural number such that $\exists f:N \rightarrow A$ with $f$ onto.  Such a smallest $N$ must exist by induction.  Prove that $f$ must be one-to-one and then show that $f^{-1}$ gets you where you need to be.

Comment: Actually, if all you need is a $1-1$ function *into* (as opposed to *onto*) a natural number, you're almost done.  Just define $g(a)$ as the least element of $I_a$ using your construction and prove that $g$ is $1-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f $ is surjective, it has a section $g:A\to n $, that's $f\circ g=\mathrm {is} $
Then $g $ is injective hence induce a bijection onto its image, that's  $A\cong  g [A] $.
Since $g [A]\subseteq n$, it is finite, hence $A$ is finite as well.